# Python If/else behaving incorrectly (or I'm just dumb)

Tags: python, selenium, http, google-analytics, python-requests

I'm still a beginner, so I'm sure the issue is in some silly thing I did.

Basically, I'm trying to figure out websites that have only one or the two versions of Google Analytics (UA --> Universal analytics, and GA4 --> Google Analytics 4).

The best way to do it in my opinion is to scrape the network requests and differentiate them using the URLs (see the difference in the variables *"ga4check"* and *"uacheck"*).

Scraping the network requests and parsing it is working fine, but when I check its presence using an if/else statement it doesn't work. It basically returns false to the first if since the output is ***"Something isn't right..."***

Here's my code :

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time
import json

ga4check = 'google-analytics.com/g/collect?v=2&tid=G-'
uacheck = 'google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&_v='
collectlist = []

if __name__ == "__main__":

    desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
    desired_capabilities["goog:loggingPrefs"] = {"performance": "ALL"}
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('headless')
    options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\dgayg\Desktop\Scripts\GA4 finder\chromedriver.exe',
                            chrome_options=options,
                            desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)

    driver.get("https://www.measureschool.com/")
    time.sleep(10)
    logs = driver.get_log("performance")

    with open("network_log.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write("[")

        for log in logs:
            network_log = json.loads(log["message"])["message"]

            if("Network.response" in network_log["method"]
                    or "Network.request" in network_log["method"]
                    or "Network.webSocket" in network_log["method"]):

                f.write(json.dumps(network_log)+",")
        f.write("{}]")

    print("Quitting Selenium WebDriver")
    driver.quit()

    json_file_path = "network_log.json"
    with open(json_file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        logs = json.loads(f.read())

    for log in logs:
        try:
            url = log["params"]["request"]["url"]

            if "collect?v=" in url:
                collectlist.append(url)
        except Exception as e:
            pass

if any(uacheck in i for i in collectlist):
    if any(ga4check in i for i in collectlist):
        print('There\'s UA and GA4 on this website')
    elif any(ga4check not in i for i in collectlist):
        print('Only UA is present on this website')
else:
    print('Something isn\'t right...')
```

Output :

```
C:\Users\dgayg\Desktop\Scripts\GA4 finder> & C:/Users/dgayg/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe "c:/Users/dgayg/Desktop/Scripts/GA4 finder/main.py"
c:\Users\dgayg\Desktop\Scripts\GA4 finder\main.py:18: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, 
please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\dgayg\Desktop\Scripts\GA4 finder\chromedriver.exe',     
c:\Users\dgayg\Desktop\Scripts\GA4 finder\main.py:18: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\dgayg\Desktop\Scripts\GA4 finder\chromedriver.exe',     

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:14224/devtools/browser/ea27a598-5b1d-48e2-bffa-1bf849b826b8
[0731/193526.701:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Failed to set referrer policy: The value '' is not one of 'no-referrer', 'no-referrer-when-downgrade', 'origin', 'origin-when-cross-origin', 'same-origin', 'strict-origin', 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin', or 'unsafe-url'. The referrer policy has been left unchanged.", source:  (0)
[0731/193526.880:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 3.3.2", source: https://measureschool.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=3.3.2 (2)
Quitting Selenium WebDriver
Something isn't right...
```

Here's the output of ***collectlist***

```
['https://region1.google-analytics.com/g/collect?v=2&tid=G-QG5JR71SF7&gtm=2oe7r0&_p=877231823&_z=ccd.v9B&cid=879701179.1659290205&ul=en-us&sr=800x600&_s=1&sid=1659290205&sct=1&seg=0&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fmeasureschool.com%2F&dt=MeasureSchool%20-%20The%20Data-Driven%20Way%20of%20Digital%20Marketing&en=page_view&_fv=1&_nsi=1&_ss=1', 'https://px.ads.linkedin.com/collect?v=2&fmt=js&pid=1024658&time=1659290205477&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmeasureschool.com%2F', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/j/collect?v=1&_v=j96&a=877231823&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fmeasureschool.com%2F&dp=%2F&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=MeasureSchool%20-%20The%20Data-Driven%20Way%20of%20Digital%20Marketing&sd=24-bit&sr=800x600&vp=774x600&je=0&_u=4CDACEABBAAAAC~&jid=253819846&gjid=797933957&cid=879701179.1659290205&tid=UA-58541733-2&_gid=1754033578.1659290206&_r=1&gtm=2wg7r0593KN2&z=952191590', 'https://px.ads.linkedin.com/collect?v=2&fmt=js&pid=1024658&time=1659290205477&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmeasureschool.com%2F&liSync=true', 'https://px4.ads.linkedin.com/collect?v=2&fmt=js&pid=1024658&time=1659290205477&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmeasureschool.com%2F&liSync=true&e_ipv6=AQJQvwc9MAD7QAAAAYJVZz8nCTxegeWWl3Feqs04Ry8lLAYe4tRStgs5YUf0ek2yseMWT3wlT2oSrFcxugGX91BzO2PCy9w']
```

I hope that what I'm trying to achieve is clear enough.

Thanks a lot in advance !!

Comment: The most obvious place to start debugging is to print `collectlist` to see if there's actually anything in there.  Since you silently discard exceptions while you're building the list, it would be easy for a single typo to cause you to get an empty result and not see any error message until your "something isn't right" condition at the end.

Comment: Hey @Samwise Thanks for your comment. I updated the post with `collectlist`'s output

Comment: None of the entries in `collectlist` seem to contain the string held in `uacheck` - so isn't "Something isn't right" the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your `collectlist`:

```
collectlist = [
    'https://region1.google-analytics.com/g/collect?v=2&tid=G-QG5JR71SF7&gtm=2oe7r0&_p=877231823&_z=ccd.v9B&cid=879701179.1659290205&ul=en-us&sr=800x600&_s=1&sid=1659290205&sct=1&seg=0&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fmeasureschool.com%2F&dt=MeasureSchool%20-%20The%20Data-Driven%20Way%20of%20Digital%20Marketing&en=page_view&_fv=1&_nsi=1&_ss=1',
    'https://px.ads.linkedin.com/collect?v=2&fmt=js&pid=1024658&time=1659290205477&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmeasureschool.com%2F',
    'https://www.google-analytics.com/j/collect?v=1&_v=j96&a=877231823&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fmeasureschool.com%2F&dp=%2F&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=MeasureSchool%20-%20The%20Data-Driven%20Way%20of%20Digital%20Marketing&sd=24-bit&sr=800x600&vp=774x600&je=0&_u=4CDACEABBAAAAC~&jid=253819846&gjid=797933957&cid=879701179.1659290205&tid=UA-58541733-2&_gid=1754033578.1659290206&_r=1&gtm=2wg7r0593KN2&z=952191590',
    'https://px.ads.linkedin.com/collect?v=2&fmt=js&pid=1024658&time=1659290205477&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmeasureschool.com%2F&liSync=true',
    'https://px4.ads.linkedin.com/collect?v=2&fmt=js&pid=1024658&time=1659290205477&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmeasureschool.com%2F&liSync=true&e_ipv6=AQJQvwc9MAD7QAAAAYJVZz8nCTxegeWWl3Feqs04Ry8lLAYe4tRStgs5YUf0ek2yseMWT3wlT2oSrFcxugGX91BzO2PCy9w'
]
```

and look at your value for `uacheck`:

```
uacheck = 'google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&_v='
```

There is not any `i` in `collectlist` that contains `uacheck`.  You do have a `ga4check` URL, but your code doesn't bother looking for `ga4check` if it doesn't find at least one `uacheck` first.

I believe you may want to structure your checks more like:

```
any_ua = any(uacheck in i for i in collectlist)
any_ga4 = any(ga4check in i for i in collectlist)

if any_ua and any_ga4:
    print('There\'s UA and GA4 on this website')
elif any_ua:
    print('Only UA is present on this website')
elif any_ga4:
    print('Only GA4 is present on this website')
else:
    print('Neither is present on this website.)
```

Since your `if`s are effectively checking all the possible combinations of two booleans, you could also represent that as a 2x2 truth table, like this:

```
any_ua = any(uacheck in i for i in collectlist)
any_ga4 = any(ga4check in i for i in collectlist)
print([
    # no GA                # some GA
    ["Neither is present", "Only GA4 is present"],  # no UA
    ["Only UA is present", "There's UA and GA4"],   # some UA
][any_ua][any_ga4], "on this website")
```